# Built-in iOS fonts with support for Chinese characters?

Tags: ios, fonts, cjk

What fonts come bundled with iOS that have a unique set of Traditional Chinese characters?

It seems the a list of fonts included in iOS 5 resides at [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com/); however, it seems that most fonts (ex: "GillSans-Bold") will use a common typeface (though I'm not sure which it is) to render Chinese characters.

So far, through trial and error, it seems the following have unique Chinese character sets:

- STHeitiSC-Medium
- STHeitiTC-Medium
- HiraKakuProN-W6

Comment: What do you mean by 'unique'?

Comment: bmargulies: If a font doesn't contain a script you're trying to use font substitution kicks in and picks glyphs from another font. Since this is usually independent of the originally selected font, you'll get a different look only from fonts that contain glyphs from the respective script.

Comment: You solved a problem I've had with certain Chinese characters displaying incorrectly on my iPhone (all I had to do was use the STHeitiSC-Medium font in the app I was using!). Thanks for this!

Comment: HiraKakuProN-W6 looks like Japanese,Japanese don't have as much characters in Chinese.As on http://iosfonts.com/, it says there are also STHeitiSC-Light and STHeitiTC-Light. Also Notice that SC means Simplified Chinese, which is used only in China mainland, and TC means Traditional Chinese, which is used in other part of world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `HiraMinProN-W6` and W3 as well, the `HiraKakuProN has a W3 version` and there are light versions of the `STHeiti* fonts`. I think that's all.

You can enumerate them with some of the Core Text functions and find them that way. Worth noting that the `STHeiti* fonts` have 51-52,000 glyphs, the Hira* ones have about 20,000